# MySQL pivot from two mysql results

Tags: mysql, select, pivot, union

My scenario is... I have 2 type of judges who will give different set of points to members (eg. Judge Type A(55%) and Judge Type B(45%)) Both set of points will sum separately and averaged and then will sum together (which is 100% in total of 2 judges' points). I want to union both results into expected output below.

```
Table Member
-----------------------------
ID | Name
1  | John
2  | Doe
-----------------------------

Table Judge
-----------------------------
ID | Type | Name
1  | 1    | Judge A
2  | 1    | Judge B
3  | 2    | Judge C
4  | 1    | Judge D
-----------------------------

Table Point
-----------------------------
ID | FK | Judge | Type | Point
1  | 1  | 1     | 1    | 10
2  | 1  | 1     | 2    | 15
3  | 1  | 1     | 3    | 15
4  | 2  | 2     | 1    | 8
5  | 2  | 2     | 2    | 6
6  | 2  | 2     | 3    | 5
7  | 2  | 3     | 4    | 3
8  | 2  | 3     | 5    | 2
9  | 2  | 3     | 6    | 1
10 | 2  | 4     | 1    | 3
11 | 2  | 4     | 2    | 6
12 | 2  | 4     | 3    | 12
-----------------------------


Output Total Points
-----------------------------
ID | Name | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Total1 | CountJudge1 | Type4 | Type5 | Type6 | Total2 | CountJudge2
1  | John | 10    | 15    | 15    | 40     | 1           | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0     
2  | Doe  | 11    | 12    | 17    | 40     | 2           | 3     | 2     | 1     | 6      | 1
-----------------------------


Expected Output
-----------------------------
ID | Name | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Total1 | CountJudge1 | Type4 | Type5 | Type6 | Total2 | CountJudge2 | TotalPoint
1  | John | 10    | 15    | 15    | 40     | 1           | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0           | 40
2  | Doe  | 5.5   | 6     | 8.5   | 20     | 2           | 3     | 2     | 1     | 6      | 1           | 26
-----------------------------
```

The sql (Output Total Points) that I could do at this moment which is still wrong is below and I can't figure out how to average all types of point and total points.

```
SELECT m.Name,

COUNT( CASE WHEN j.Type=1 THEN j.ID ELSE 0 END ) AS Judge1,
SUM( CASE WHEN p.Type=1 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END ) AS Type1, 
SUM( CASE WHEN p.Type=2 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END ) AS Type2, 
SUM( CASE WHEN p.Type=3 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END ) AS Type3, 
SUM( p.Score ) AS Total1,

COUNT( CASE WHEN j.Type=2 THEN j.ID ELSE 0 END ) AS Judge2,
SUM( CASE WHEN p.Type=4 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END ) AS Type4, 
SUM( CASE WHEN p.Type=5 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END ) AS Type5, 
SUM( CASE WHEN p.Type=6 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END ) AS Type6, 
SUM( p.Score ) AS Total2

FROM table_point AS p
LEFT JOIN table_member AS m ON ( m.ID = p.FK)
LEFT JOIN table_judge AS j ON ( j.ID = p.Judge )

GROUP BY m.ID
```

*** UPDATE 1 ***

I figured out the statement for expected result. However, as data grows bigger, my statement get slower. (250 members, 13 judges, 9750 scores (3 scores per judge per student) takes bout +-6 seconds). When I doubled members and scores, the execution time also doubled. Any idea to optimize this query?

```
SELECT  MemberID, MemberName, 
Judge1, Score1, Score2, Score3, 
Judge2, Score4, Score5, Score6,
(((Score1 + Score2 + Score3) / (Judge1 / 3)) + ((Score4 + Score5 + Score6) / (Judge2 / 3))) AS TotalScore

FROM
(
SELECT m.ID AS MemberID, m.Name AS MemberName,

COUNT(j1.ID) AS Judge1,
SUM(CASE WHEN p.TypeID=1 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END) AS Score1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN p.TypeID=2 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END) AS Score2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN p.TypeID=3 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END) AS Score3, 

COUNT(j2.ID) AS Judge2,
SUM(CASE WHEN p.TypeID=4 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END) AS Score4, 
SUM(CASE WHEN p.TypeID=5 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END) AS Score5, 
SUM(CASE WHEN p.TypeID=6 THEN p.Point ELSE 0 END) AS Score6 

FROM table_point AS p
LEFT JOIN table_member AS m ON ( m.ID = p.FK)
LEFT JOIN table_judge AS j1 ON ( j1.ID = p.Judge AND j1.Type=1 )
LEFT JOIN table_judge AS j2 ON ( j2.ID = p.Judge AND j2.Type=2 )

GROUP BY m.ID 
) as tbl1

ORDER BY TotalScore DESC
```